# How to access scope containing arrays in directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have this `$scope` containing array basically I use service to get those this is the code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

myApp.controller('GetItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    var itemUrl = 'json/item.json';
    $http({url: itemUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: '',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //check if the response has ok status
        if(data.status == "ok"){
        console.log(data.data);
            $scope.items = data.data;
        }


        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log('error');

    });

}]);
```

and also I do have a draggable item and droppable div, basically I will just drag item then drop it to the droppable div. this is the code for draggable

```
myApp.directive('draggable', function() {
  return {
      link: function (scope, element) {
         $(element).draggable({
            helper: function(){
              return $("<tr></tr>").append($(this).find('.img').clone());
            },
              revert: 'original',
              cursor: "move",
            revert: "invalid",
            cursorAt: {top: 5, left: 5 } ,
            zIndex: 100,
            tolerance:"pointer",
            start: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).css('opacity', '.5');

            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).css('opacity', '1');

            }
         });
      } 
    }
});
```

the html for draggable is this

```
<tr id="{{ item.Item.itemnumber}}" data-ng-repeat-start="item in items" draggable class="draggableItem">
                <td><img class="img" id="{{ item.Item.itemnumber }}" width="50px" 
                        src="source here"/></td>
                <td>{{ item.Item.itemnumber}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Item.itemtext1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Item.recommended_price}}</td>
</tr>
```

my problem is I want to access the `$scope.items` in my controller from my directive (droppable) this is the code for droppable :

```
myApp.directive('droppable', function() {
  return {

      link: function (scope, element) {
         $(element).droppable({
            accept: "#itemlist .draggableItem",
            hoverClass: "dropHover",
            activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {

        //I WANT TO ACCESS THE $scope.items HERE

        console.log(ui);
            }
        });
      } 
    }
});
```

and the droppable is like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="tempElement in templateElements" class="bg-default border-solid droppable" droppable="" >
{{ tempElement.TemplateElement.elementname }}
 </div>
```

I have tried this inside my droppable directive but it change nothing also it disable the div droppable capabilities I guess i have error somewhere but the console wont print any.

```
restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
      items: '=items'
    },
```

could anyone help me access the $scope containing arrays in my directives.

thank you in advance for any comments and ideas.

Comment: Show your html structure

Comment: do a `console.log(scope)` in your directive and it will show you the scope you are in, and the accessible scopes. Useful for traversing these scopes.

Comment: @No1_Melman i dont see the scope `items` but i have seen some other scope i used but not the items

Comment: Is your directive within the scope of your controller in terms of HTML? so `<div ng-controller="MyController"><my-directive></my-directive></div>`

Comment: @No1_Melman the scope i'm accessing is not in the same controller, in that case what would be my work around

Comment: transclude? look at the angular docs, they do go extensive on scopes when using directives